# How to automate the process of IVR

Tags: ivr

Could anyone let me know how to automate the process of IVR like to make unit testing on IVR composer without making testing calling every time? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Kind of depends on what skills you have and what test you want, but here are some options:

- Back2Back: probably the quickest and easiest solution is to have 2 copies of your IVR. Make one call the other and (depending on which of the two you want to test) have one be passive (= do nothing until hangup) and let the other run the flow/script you want to test.
- Test tool: take something you can script or code to build a call generator tool. Usually this is something like FreeSwitch or if you have code skills, a SIP stack like PJSIP where you build your own sip client. There are also some commercial options in this area, google for something like "SIP Test Tool" and you'll probably find something.
- Get creative: I've seen QA engineers abuse standard HTTP web test tool to generate SIP messages. Anything capable of scripted responses (so you can send ACK and such) can work here, but depends on your specific needs. It can be a cheap and easy solution if you know what you're doing and you don't need things like interactive audio.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you can write a simple app for that testing using [Dasha](https://dasha.ai/).

Sample DSL (DashaScript) code:

```
start node root {
    do {
        #connectSafe("<PHONE_NUMBER>"); //make Dasha call your IVR
    }
    transitions {
        step2: goto step2 on #messageHasIntent("press_one"); //use conversational AI to understand that IVR says "press one to ..."
    }
}

node step2 {
    do {
        #sendDTMF("1"); //make selection by sending DTMF code
    }
    transitions {
        step3: goto step3 on #messageHasIntent("press_two");
    }
}

node step3 {
    do {
        #sendDTMF("2");
    }
}

//etc......
```

So you can design test suites for IVRs and even generate them automatically or make it a part of your CI/CD process.

If you need any help, feel free to join our [dev community](http://community.dasha.ai/) or drop me a line at vlad@dasha.ai.

Cheers